# Preventing php-fpm from installing default conf file when updating over yum

Tags: yum, php-fpm

Each time I update php-fpm on my server it installs a new www.conf file that interferes with my existing configuration. Is there any way to block it from being overwritten each time?

Comment: As a side note, one may want to version control important configuration files, e.g., `cd /etc/ ; sudo git init ; sudo git add . ; sudo git commit -m 'initial'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rpm should be creating a new www.conf called www.conf.rpmsave or www.conf.rpmnew if the www.conf already exists, it shouldn't be overwriting it.

If your configuration doesn't have a www.conf, the easy solution would be to just touch www.conf to make a new, blank one. If you ARE using www.conf and it is still overwriting it, then you're probably going to have to get heavy-handed with it.

```
chattr +i /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```

Should do the trick. This will prevent anything anywhere from overwriting the file again. Next time you need to make a change to it, you'll have to use `chattr -i` on it, make your changes, then use `chattr +i` to reprotect it. These commands will have to be performed with root privileges (no surprise).

Comment: Thanks, though my real question is why there isn't a pools-available and pools-enabled…